# Как повесить события `change` на все элементы формы

Tags: javascript

Хочу избавиться в своем скрипте от jQuery.

Суть скрипта:

1. загрузить форму по ajax
2. повесить обработчик на изменение формы

Не получается нормально повесить обработчик на события изменения формы. На ванильном JS как я понял, на всю форму повесить нельзя, приходится на каждый элемент в отдельности.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        var resp = request.responseText;
        container.innerHTML = resp;
        var form = container.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
        if (form !== undefined) {
            var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input, select');
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                inputs[i].addEventListener('change', calculate(calcID, url));
            }
        }
    }
};
request.send();

function calculate(calcID, url) {}
```

Проблема: после загрузки формы сразу происходит вызов обработчика столько раз, сколько инпутов в форме. Событие не вешается (при изменении значений инпутов обработчик не вызывается)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function handle(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log(event.type, event.target);
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('change', handle);
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', handle);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text name=a>
  <input type=radio name=b value=1>
  <input type=radio name=b value=2>
  <input type=radio name=b value=3>
  <input type=checkbox name=c value=4>
  <input type=checkbox name=c value=5>
  <input type=checkbox name=c value=6>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот это

```
calculate(calcID, url)
```

и есть непосредственный вызов функции.

Надо:

```
inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() { calculate(calcID, url); });
```

или

```
var handler = function() { calculate(calcID, url); };
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', handler);
}
```

Comment: Понял, значит только через анонимную функцию. Ушел учить матчасть. Зааппрувлю ответ через 9 минут, раньше не даёт :)

Comment: Бррррррррррр...